# Ruby/Rails ActionMailer not working with NTLM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exchange-server, actionmailer

I am setting up a mailer in my project and I am having difficulties sending mail through Exchange SMTP server.

I have installed the gem `ruby-ntlm` but I am still getting `unrecognized authentication type`.

This is my code

**environment.rb**

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
require 'ntlm/smtp'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

**notifier.rb**

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "stephen.edwards@foostix.lu"

  def test
    mail(:to => "stephen.edwards@foostix.lu", :subject => "Test subject").deliver
  end
end
```

**development.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "**REMOVED**",
    :port => 587, 
    :domain => "CMSAD",   
    :user_name => "**REMOVED**", 
    :password => "**REMOVED**", 
    :authentification => :ntlm,
    :enable_starttls_auto => false
  }
```

**Rails console test**

```
Notifier#test: processed outbound mail in 5591.8ms
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type

        from /home/stephen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:968:in `check_auth_response'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:739:in `auth_plain'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:731:in `authenticate'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:566:in `do_start'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:527:in `block in deliver_mail'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:525:in `deliver_mail'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `deliver'
        from /media/development/Foostix-web/app/mailers/notifier.rb:5:in `test'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
... 15 levels...
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /media/development/Foostix-web/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/stephen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

**However this works....**

```
smtp = Net::SMTP.new('**REMOVED**', 587)
smtp.debug_output = $stdout
smtp.enable_starttls_auto#skip if not needed
smtp.start("CMSAD", "**REMOVED**", "**REMOVED**", :ntlm)

TLS connection started
<- "EHLO CMSAD\r\n"
-> "250-**REMOVED** Hello [**REMOVED**]\r\n"
-> "250-SIZE 104857600\r\n"
-> "250-PIPELINING\r\n"
-> "250-DSN\r\n"
-> "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n"
-> "250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN\r\n"
-> "250-8BITMIME\r\n"
-> "250-BINARYMIME\r\n"
-> "250 CHUNKING\r\n"
<- "AUTH NTLM **REMOVED**==\r\n"
-> "334 **REMOVED**\r\n"
<- **REMOVED**\r\n"
-> "235 2.7.0 Authentication successful\r\n"
 => #<Net::SMTP **REMOVED** started=true>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a typo, it is now working!

**development.rb**

Change `:authentification => :ntlm` to `:authentication  => :ntlm`

Thanks for the support anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't included the `ntlm` library.

Add the NTLM SMTP library to your `config/environment.rb` file

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

require 'ntlm/smtp' # ADD THIS LINE HERE

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```