# How to configure Rails mailer with a non-gmail account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a rails mailer that I want to configure with an email account that is non-gmail, and is accessed through outlook. the SMTP address is "smtp.us.exg7.exghost.com". The email **is not** @exghost.com.

I am running into a 504 5.7.4 unrecognized authentication type error.

Here is my configuration:

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {

    :address => "smtp.us.exg7.exghost.com",

    :port => "587",

    :domain => "exghost.org",

    :user_name => 'example@example.org', 

    :password => 'Password',

    :authentication => "plain",

    :enable_starttls_auto => true

     }
```

Does anyone have any insight into this? I have tried various domains- `exghost.com`, `us.exg7.exghost.com`, `example.org`. I have tried changing authentication from "`plain`" to "`login`", but nothing seems to change the error.

I know that in gmail you have to allow third-party access, does this need to be done with other formats?

Comment: I think this question will be of your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523348/cannot-get-actionmailer-working-with-ms-exchange-via-smtp my guess is that there's an issue with your SMTP server, can you debug which authentication methods does it support?

Comment: It looks like these are the auth methods `smtp.us.exg7.exghost.com` supports `AUTH: GSSAPI NTLM`

Comment: An here are some insights of how could you make action mailer support NTLM auth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673720/ruby-rails-actionmailer-not-working-with-ntlm